# The prototype is returning my function instead of the return value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, prototype

I want to create the subtitle of my pages similar to the image
[image]

And I want to do this by calling my prototype from main.js

```
Vue.prototype.subtitlePage = function () {
  var path = this.$route.path;
  var array_path = path.split('/');
  var subtitle = "<ul class='subtitle'>";
  var index;
  for (index = 1; index < array_path.length - 2; index++) {
    subtitle += "<li>" + array_path[index] + "</li> >>";
  }
  subtitle += "<li>" + array_path[index] + "</li><ul>";
  return subtitle;
}
```

I'm calling my function that way in the construction of my screen

```
<p class="indextitle">Subir Nova Redação</p>
<p v-html="subtitlePage"></p>
```

However the text that appears on the screen is not the html return mounted in the function, but the code of my function

```
function () { var path = this.$route.path; var array_path = path.split('/'); var subtitle = "
"; var index; for (index = 1; index < array_path.length - 2; index++) { subtitle += "
" + array_path[index] + "
>>"; } subtitle += "
" + array_path[index] + "
"; return subtitle; }
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and what I have to change in my code to appear in the subtitle what I set up in the function?

Comment: Thats the correct behavior according to the docs. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML   .... It's outputting the html, in your case its a whole function.. If you dig around on the net you will find a working example or two.

Comment: it's not the prototype that is returning the text of the function, it's how `subtitlePage` is being used - any function accessed without `()` and as a string (either by using `functionName.toString()` or having been coerced, i.e. `'' + functionName`) will result in the function body being returned like that - perhaps `v-html` doesn't expect a function name as an argument?

Comment: Route path elements sound like the kinds of things that an attacker might control; for example by getting the user to click on a link where they've crafted the URL path.  This code should probably HTML escape or sanitize `array_path[index]` before appending it to `subtitle` to avoid XSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`v-html` expects a string](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html), while a function is given, this results in stringified function output. It should be:

```
<p v-html="subtitlePage()"></p>
```

**This should never be done in practice with user-defined data.**

> Dynamically rendering arbitrary HTML on your website can be very dangerous because it can easily lead to XSS attacks. Only use v-html on trusted content and never on user-provided content.

URL is user-defined data here. It can be tailored by a culprit to evaluate arbitrary JS on user side.

A correct way to do this is to create a component for a breadcrumb and output it with:

```
<li v-for="pathSegment in pathSegments">{{pathSegment}}</li>
```

In case a segment may contain URL-encoded symbols (spaces and non-ASCII characters in this example), segments need to be additionally transformed with `decodeURIComponent` (this isn't covered in original code and will be a primary hazard for `v-html`).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it as follows

```
Vue.mixin({
  computed: {
    subtitlePage: {
      get: function () {
        var path = this.$route.path;
        var array_path = path.split('/');
        var subtitle = "<ul class='subtitle'>";
        var index;
        for (index = 1; index < array_path.length - 2; index++) {
          subtitle += "<li>" + array_path[index] + "</li> >>";
        }
        subtitle += "<li>" + array_path[index] + "</li><ul>";
        return subtitle; 
      }
    }
  }
})
```